# Java Filechooser Looping

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jfilechooser

I'm working on a program that opens up the `JFileChooser` and allows the user to choose a .txt file which contains information like name, height, and weight.

The program then calculates the BMI for each person listed in the file and displays them in a JOptionPane. They can then decide whether to choose another file or cancel the program.

I have everything figured out for the calculations and displaying them, but the difficulty I'm having is with the `JOptionPane` choices. I want to display a message whenever the user chooses the "no" option or when they cancel choosing a file, but I seem to not be able to do so. I'm also unsure how to reopen the `JFileChooser` whenever they choose the "yes" option. If anyone could provide some guidance on how to achieve this or even what I may be doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate the help. Thank you in advance! This is my code thus far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    readFile();
}

public static int readFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    int choice = (JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

    while (choice == (JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)) {
        File file;
        JFileChooser fileChooser;

        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        while (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

            String report = BMIRecord.report(file);

            int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, report + "\n\nWould you like to try another file?", "BMI Calculations", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            return choice;
        }

    }

    while (choice == (JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Session ended.");
        return choice;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return choice` is going to exit the method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the loops are confusing the issue.  You only need a single loop, the way that prompts the user for a new file and prompts the user to continue...

Basically, you need to prompt for a file, if the `JFileChooser` returns with `JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`, you calculate the BMI and display the report and can then prompt the user for another file.  Otherwise, you can probably assume they've chosen not to continue.

You keep doing this until `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` becomes equal to `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION` (or the user cancels the `JFileChooser`, which is probably the same thing)

Something like...

```
public static int readFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int choice = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;
    do {
        choice = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            String report = BMIRecord.report(file);
            choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, report + "\n\nWould you like to try another file?", "BMI Calculations", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        }

    } while (choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

    return 0;
}
```

For example...(ps, I'm not sure what the method is "suppose" to return, so I just returned `0`)

Comment: This doesn't take into account if the cancel option is chosen for the JFileChooser.

Comment: @Shar1er80 What do you think  `choice = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;` and `if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {` are doing....

Comment: You're implying that canceling the JFileChooser is the same thing as not wanting to choose another file (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( )).  I just don't consider that to be the same is all.  No disrespect intended.

Comment: No taken, but I've just assumed, if you cancel the file chooser, the user doesn't want to continue, that's just how I think (and as a use, if you prompted me with a "do you want to continue?" Question, I'd be yelling lots of choice phrases at you, but again, that's just me ;))

Comment: @Shar1er80 ps- I thought you were suggesting that there was a logic error ;) - it's a valid comment to make, as the op may no want it to work this way and prefer it work the way you've suggested

Comment: Thank you so much MadProgrammer and @Shar1er80 for your help! I understand better where I was going wrong now.

Comment: @Claire Glad it all helped

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your two while loops, after the first while loop, should be if statements.  Also, don't return choice.  Instead, have it receive the result from JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog().

```
public static int readFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    int choice=(JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    while(choice == (JOptionPane.YES_OPTION))
    {
        File file;
        JFileChooser fileChooser;

        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        // If statement, instead of while
        String report = "";
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

            report = BMIRecord.report(file);
        }

        // Ask for another file regardless of the result of the fileChooser
        choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, report + "\n\nWould you like to try another file?","BMI Calculations",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
    }

    // If statement, instead of while.  Also, this if isn't really needed.  Once the while loop exits, the NO_OPTION is implied to have been selected.    
    if (choice == (JOptionPane.NO_OPTION))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Session ended.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```